# jQuery change innerHtml of a group of radio buttons labels with a onClick listener using data-target

Tags: html, jquery, innerhtml

I have multiple groups of radio buttons. Names and Id's dynamically via variables. Each radio button has a label that I use (via css) as a button instead of the radio button itself (hidden).

when I click on a label, I need two things to happen:

1. all labels in that group of radio buttons to have their innerHtml reset to xxxx
2. the clicked labels innerHtml set to yyyy

The second part I can do. Its the first part I have trouble with. Maybe there is need to do it as a loop? But anyway, tried it with a single radio button first, couldn't make it work

```js
$(document).on('click', '.n', function() {
  $('label[for^=$(this).data("target")]').html("xxxx");
  $("#" + $(this).data("target") + "label").html("yyyy");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="1" name="na" value="" />
<label for="1" data-target="1" id="1label" class="n" selected>yyyy</label>
<input type="radio" id="2" name="na" value="" />
<label for="2" data-target="2" id="2label" class="n">xxxx</label>
<input type="radio" id="3" name="na" value="" />
<label for="3" data-target="3" id="3label" class="n">xxxx</label>
```

Comment: Where is the `.pcconfig-radio-styled-buttons` element? Also, you're not concatenating the  `$(this).data('target')` value in to the first selector string correctly.

Comment: ah, forgot to change it to "n" in the example, in the real code the classes are correct :-) "you're not concatenating the $(this).data('target') value in to the first selector string correctly." - could I maybe ask you to elaborate on this? Probably the whole issue that I don't know how to do this... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below, hope it is clear:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.n', function() {
    var thisLabel = $(this);
    var thisDataTarget = thisLabel.data('target');
    var thisTarget = $('#'+thisDataTarget);
    var thisGroupName = thisTarget.attr('name');
    $('input[name='+thisGroupName+']').each(function(i) {
        var loopInput = $(this);
        var loopID = loopInput.attr('id');
        var loopText = loopID==thisDataTarget ? 'yyyy' : 'xxxx';
        $('label[for='+loopID+']').html( loopText );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="1" name="na" value="" />
<label for="1" data-target="1" id="1label" class="n" selected>yyyy</label>
<input type="radio" id="2" name="na" value="" />
<label for="2" data-target="2" id="2label" class="n">xxxx</label>
<input type="radio" id="3" name="na" value="" />
<label for="3" data-target="3" id="3label" class="n">xxxx</label>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/t3bzfqh9/12/).

Comment: SWEET :-) Works. Thank you very much. And very clear with the var definitions in the beginning.

Comment: Hmmm, are there something in your code that does not allow the name of the radiobutton group name to be an array? Replaced with the actual naming now and it throws an error (jquery.js?v=20200024&ver=6797faf:31 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=dcs_computer_type_form[motherboard]]) - the actual naming is like this (sorry, realize now I should probably have put that in the question, just wanted it to look more simple at first sight):

Comment: <input type="radio" id="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard993268453" name="dcs_computer_type_form[motherboard]" value="" />
    <label for="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard993268453" data-target="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard993268453" id="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard993268453label" class="pcconfig-radio-styled-buttons" selected>yyyy</label>

Comment: <input type="radio" id="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard995007553" name="dcs_computer_type_form[motherboard]" value="" />
    <label for="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard995007553" data-target="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard995007553" id="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard995007553label" class="pcconfig-radio-styled-buttons">xxxx</label>

Comment: <input type="radio" id="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard994893224" name="dcs_computer_type_form[motherboard]" value="" />
    <label for="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard994893224" data-target="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard994893224" id="dcs_computer_type_form_motherboard994893224label" class="pcconfig-radio-styled-buttons">xxxx</label>

Comment: Just put the name under quotes. For example `input[name="dcs_computer_type_form[motherboard]"]`

Comment: Hmmmm ... I have a little naming conflict. Also to make it more "safe", would it be possible to add another condition to the labels being updated? fx that they should also have class="pcconfig-radio-styled-buttons" to be affected?

Comment: I really think you've started the code wrong way and therefor you have problems. I would suggest to generate html code somehow better, to be easily accessed later on via javascript. First of all, try to place your inputs inside labels and than you will need no data targets, for and other attributes/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly and solved it with this code snippet:

```js
// loop over all labels
$('label').each(function () {
  // add onclick listeners to all labels
  $(this).on('click', function () {
    // set each label's innerhtml to xxxx
    $('label').each(function () {
      $(this).html('xxxx')
    })
    // set currently clicked label's innerhtml to yyyy
    $(this).html('yyyy')
  })
})
```

Example: https://codepen.io/SubhumanWasTaken/pen/MWKZPrb

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, its not all labels on the page that needs to be reset, there need to be a condition: $('label[for^=$(this).data("target")]').html("xxxx") .... the "for" attribute needs to be the data-target that is being sent with the on-click event. And its this line that has a bug ... somewhere. The rest works...

Comment: so the condition is that the label while being clicked has to contain `xxxx`? So this is not possible if the label contains `yyyy`?

Comment: subhuman, no, the condition is that the for attribute should be (this).data("target"). Thank you for your help - but the other answer seems to do what I wanted it to do... :-)